# Something Went Wrong while modifying view

Tags: list-view

**I am unable to modify any view my site** while I am using administrator account and trying to modify a list view, I get error. Following is the description/log of error.

Timestamp : 03/13/2017 18:49:43.15

Process: w3wp.exe (0x1E14)

Tid: 0x23E8

Area: SharePoint Foundation

Category: Logging Correlation Data

EventID: xmnv

Level: Medium

Message: Name=Request (GET:http://mylocahost/_layouts/15/ViewEdit.aspx?List=%7BF2AA9293%2DD86E%2D4805%2DAAB1%2D62AC868454B8%7D&View=%7B13CE9C9C%2D2F9D%2D49F0%2D8083%2D7C8FF1BA5AC6%7D&Source=%252F%255Flayouts%252F15%252Flistedit%252Easpx%253FList%253D%25257BF2AA9293%25252DD86E%25252D4805%25252DAAB1%25252D62AC868454B8%25257D)

CorrelationId: fa93dd9d-4977-00c5-866d-22877f830582

More: Sometime i get error, when i try to set permissions, sometime other activity

Comment: Is this a migrated list? I've seen this effects on migrated lists and activated Minimal Download Strategy feature.

Comment: Sorry, not sure about it, perhaps renamed or migrated. But is there a solution if it is migrated or renamed?

Comment: You could check whether the EnableMinimalDownload property set to false helps if it is activated and not needed for any reason of course. If this does not help I can't imagine that anything else than rebuilding will solve it.

Comment: @Celophysis Editing master page aspx caused it. Thanks for your cooperation.
Very sad to realize that being newbie to share-point, i did not know that share-point does not even warn you about anything while you are making modification to master page aspx. I could not know what had been broken by that editing, i was just checking if my pages were working and they had been fine.